# How can i calculate the average of fields and exclude the 0 values

Tags: mysql, average

I have this:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(coffee)) 'coffee',
    ROUND(AVG(cappucino)) 'cappucino',
    ROUND(AVG(espresso)) 'espresso',
    ROUND(AVG(machine)) 'machine'
    FROM `reviews` ORDER BY `username`
```

My Table looks like:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id  | name      | coffee        | cappucino     | espresso      | machine       |
+-----+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1  | Joe       | 5             | 4             | 5             | 4             |
|  2  | Jane      | 3             | 5             | 2             | 5             |
|  3  | Mike      | 0             | 0             | 0             | 5             |
+-----+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I need the average of the reviews but Mike doesn't drink any coffee and he clicked the "Does not apply" button. So the current average is:

```
coffee 2.66666667
cappucino 3
espresso 2.33333333
machine 4.66666667
```

But it should be:

```
coffee 4
cappucino 4.5
espresso 3.5
machine 4.66666667
```

How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the fix:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(coffee,0))) 'coffee',
    ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(cappucino,0))) 'cappucino',
    ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(espresso,0))) 'espresso',
    ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(machine,0))) 'machine'
    FROM `reviews` ORDER BY `username`
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL values are ignored by AVG, so do `AVG(NULLIF(coffee,0))`.  Or store NULL instead of 0 in the first place.

Comment: I forgot about nullif.  Great.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a great question. I have come up with a solution.

```
 select avg(coffee) from data where coffee>0 union select avg(cappucino) from data where cappucino >0 union select avg(expresso) from data where expresso>0 union select avg(machine) from data where machine>0;
```

Try this. I'm calculating averages of all fields separately using the where condition that the value in the field should be greater than 0 and then I am displaying the UNION of all queries.

This will be the output... To avoid getting avg(coffee) as the column header, you may use ALIAS.

```
+-------------+
| avg(coffee) |
+-------------+
|      4.0000 |
|      4.5000 |
|      3.5000 |
|      4.6667 |
+-------------+
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: That could work, but i used a short version and used the NULLIF function. That shortens the whole query a lot. But Thanks.